# Failed to sample data: com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$DescriptorValidationException: ".google.protobuf.Timestamp" is not defined

Tags: apache-kafka, classpath, confluent-schema-registry, druid, druid-extensions

**(SEE UPDATE BELOW)**

I am trying to read events from a kafka topic using Apache Druid (v29.0.0). I successfully connected to the Kafka clusters and schema registry, so I am able to read the serialized data along with fetching the schemas.

When I go to deserialize the data read from the kafka topic I am getting the error `Failed to sample data: com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$DescriptorValidationException: <schema subject field> ".google.protobuf.Timestamp" is not defined.` I also noticed that the classes in  `druid/lib/protobuf-java.jar` all exist in `druid/extensions/druid-protobuf-extensions/druid-protobuf-extensions.jar` but I am not sure if the issue is a dependency/classpath issue or something else.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UDPATE: RESOLVED**

For context, I was following this tutorial https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/protobuf/#when-using-schema-registry to enable consuming protobuf messages from kafka.

In my environment, common types (beginning with `google.protobuf.*`) were purposely left out of a schemas references. Since `kafka-protobuf-provider-6.0.1.jar` does not have the functionality to automatically add the common types if they are not present in the schema reference, druid was not able to resolve the types (see error above). Had the `google.protobuf.*` types been included in my schema's references, I would not have encountered this error.

Instead you need to use version `kafka-protobuf-provider-6.2.0.jar` or higher (see [this commit in confluent schema-registry](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/commit/3e14830043e6807dd432a650b72223587ee17568) for context). And to make this work, I needed to import additional jars (all of them from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent). These are the jars I now have under `extensions/druid-protobuf-extensions`:

```
druid-protobuf-extensions % ls -ltr
- druid-protobuf-extensions-29.0.0.jar
- kotlin-stdlib-1.4.0.jar
- kafka-protobuf-provider-6.2.0.jar
- kafka-protobuf-types-6.2.0.jar
- wire-runtime-3.6.0.jar
- wire-schema-3.6.0.jar
- proto-google-common-protos-2.36.0.jar
```

Hope this helps anybody encountering the same issue!